# Display grand total only once in a matrix report

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a matrix report designed as shown in below image

[image]

Tablix1 with Product Row Grouping:

[image]

Tablix2 with SubTotal and GrandTotal:

[image]

I added a matrix with Column grouping CategoryId and 2 tablixes in the matrix. One tablix has the Product Row grouping and the other Tablix to display Sub Total and Grand Total.

SubTotal should be displayed under each Category but the GrandTotal should be displayed only once. But, as per my design GrandTotal is showing under each category. Is there a solution to hide the Grandtotal keeping only the first column set? or any other alternate to fix the issue?

Current Result:

1. Grand Total is shown under each category.
2. Border Lines in the report is not displaying for the rows which does not have any data.

[image]
Expected Result:

1. Grand Total should be displayed only once in the report.
2. Border lines should be covered even if there is no data in the row.

[image]

Note: CategoryId is used only in the grouping and not displayed in the report.

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can't see the full design I'm not sure if there is a way to simplify it, I feel like the design is not quite right...

However, you should be able to set the hidden `property` of the textbox to something like

```
=Fields!CategoryID.Value = FIRST(Fields!CategoryID.Value, "myDataset")
```

Change `myDataset` to be the name of you actual dataset, This is case sensitive and must be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! Do we have an option to display the border lines even when there is no data?

Comment: You need to ask a separate question but generally, if a textbox is hidden, it's borders are too. Better to get the value expression to return an empty string if you don’t want to "hide" the text. If you do post another question, make sure you show your full report design as I have a feeling there is something inherently wrong with it as it is.

Comment: Posted as a different question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65253136/issue-with-border-lines-in-a-matrix-report